# How can I solve a trigonometric equation in wxMaxima such as sin(x)=0.3 across a range of x (range is [0, 4%pi])

Tags: trigonometry, maxima, wxmaxima

How can I structure this equation?
I have tried doing this:

```
x:[0,4%pi];
solve(sin(x)=0.3,x);
```

and then solving for the equation but that didn't work because:

```
%pi is not an infix operator
```

Any suggestions and also how to solve the following in wxMaxima.

[image: 1]

Comment: If you may, could you please put that as an answer so I may mark it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, I have done so. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For input, you have to show multiplication as `4*%pi` (i.e., put in the asterisk). But aside from that, solve doesn't know how to restrict solutions to a range; you would solve for unspecified x and then filter the results.

If you only need a numerical solution, try: `find_root(sin(x) = 0.3, x, 0, %pi/2)` for example. Since there are multiple solutions of sin(x) = 0.3, for find_root, you have to restrict the range to contain one of them.